# php zookeeper watcher doesn't work

Tags: php, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to use zookeeper in a php app, and I've done most of the `get($path)`/`set($path, $value)`/`getChildren($path)` functions following https://github.com/andreiz/php-zookeeper, except the `watch_callback` function that just doesn't work.

My php version is 5.6.14 and thread safety disabled, and I'm using apache2.4.

Here is some code snippet

```
class Zookeeper_Module {

    private $zookeeper;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->ci = & get_instance();
        $zookeeper_server = $this->ci->config->item('zookeeper_server');

        $this->zookeeper = new Zookeeper($zookeeper_server);
    }

    public function set($path, $value){
        $this->zookeeper->set($path, $value);
    }

    public function get($path, $watch_cb = null){
        return $this->zookeeper->get($path, $watch_cb);
    }

    public function get_watch_cb($event_type = '', $stat = '', $path = ''){
        error_log('hello from get_watcher_cb');
        $value = $this->get($path, array($this, 'get_watch_cb'));
        // update redis cache
        $this->ci->cache->redis->save('some cache key', $value);
    }
}

class MyTest{
    public function get(){
        $zookeeper = new Zookeeper_Module ();

        $value = $zookeeper->get( '/foo/bar', array (
            $zookeeper,
            'get_watch_cb'
        ) );
    }

    public function set(){
        $zookeeper = new Zookeeper_Module ();
        $zookeeper->set( '/foo/bar', 'some value');
    }
}
```

I can successfully get or set a node value, but I can neither catch watch callback log nor have redis cache updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a more simple demo, very similar with this https://github.com/andreiz/php-zookeeper/wiki, and the watcher works fine in this demo.

The most significant difference is

```
while( true ) {
    echo '.';
    sleep(2);
}
```

While java has a jvm container hosting watchers, php doesn't has a container to do it, so we have to use a `while(true)` to keep watchers alive.

So I add a `while(true)` in my code and now the watcher works fine.

But I don't want to add a terrible `while(true)` in a web app, so the final solution is adding a java app to communicate with zookeeper and save results in redis, and php app just reads info from redis.